# PPP Q&A clarifying submitTxConstraintsWith parameters - lookups and tx

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

Can someone please explain the difference between the two sets of constraints supplied to submitTxConstraintsWith?

1st question:
The function takes two parameters, referred to as "lookups" and "tx" in the examples, which are both a set of constraints. So what differentiates the "lookup" constraints from the "tx"?  Another way to frame this is, what constraints go into "lookups" and what constraints go into "tx"?

2nd question:
Conceptually, what does the term "lookup" refer to?  What is being looked up?  The term is used throughout the documentation without any definition I can find.

Answer (score 2):

"tx" constraints determine what goes into the transaction. "lookup" constraints determine which information is needed to validate the transaction, i.e. information from the blockchain or from the wallet.